# Website taking forever to load

Tags: wordpress, web

I have installed mybb in /forum and wordpress in /blog
Frequently, my wordpress blog doest not load (feels like the web server doesn't respond)
and at the same time, mybb also does not load
**note: this happens very frequently but is fixed automatically after sometime**

I have tried using Chrome and opera
----Chrome sometimes just keeps loading and sometime give "no data recieved"
----Opera simply keeps loading, loading and loading

First i thought this happens only with me but when i asked my friend to open my site, it happened with him too

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't get hit very often,  you may find that your web server is effectively turning itself off due to inactivity.

So when you visit it after a "long" period of inactivity, it takes a while while it load the application, rebuilds the cache etc.. ie the same as restarting the web application.

You can be sure this is *not* the problem, if you experience the "not responding" behaviour while you are actively browsing the site.

Comment: I am able to access cPanel even when the site does not load. Does that make difference? And yes, i experience this "not responding" behaviour while you are actively browsing the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aggregating contents then wordpress is not your choice. However I found cache plugins like quickcache can solve your problem.

Comment: nah....i need wordpress only. btw, how am i supposed to install this plugin when i'm unable to access the cPanel

Comment: You don't need cpanel access go to your wordpress admin, expand plugins tab and click add new plugin

Comment: Oh sorry.....that was a mistake. I meant- how am i supposed to install this plugin when i'm unable to access the wp-admin